# Converting multiple numbers to letters in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wanted to write a rarther simple cipher program that can convert numbers to letters. So the user provides numbers as input and it gets decoded by the program and that's how you would read the secret message. The problem is that to be able to iterate through numbers i need variable type string and to (add 95 because of ascii codes) i need type int.

i have tried to take input as a string, i have tried converting it to int. I have even tried to convert it in the for loop to an int but i still get an error either that it has to be string or that this variable needs to an int.

```py
a = int(input("Enter a number: "))

for numbers in a:
    number = chr(numbers) + 95

print (number)
```

Comment: Why are you looping over a single integer?

Comment: Hey @Ezic it's not super clear to me exactly what you are trying to do but it sounds like it's not exactly clear to you either? :) I mean no disrespect, but maybe have a quick look through the basics here: https://www.learnpython.org and maybe you will get some ideas?
If you really want an answer to this particular question, I suggest being a little bit more specific about what you mean by "convert numbers to letters".
Maybe something like:
`python -c "print(''.join(chr(int(n)+96) for n in input('Enter some numbers, separated by spaces: ').split(' ')))"` (try with the input 8 5 12 12 15).

Comment: @AndréLaszlo that was exactly what i wanted thank you ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem seems to be that you need to convert back and forth between different data types: strings, list of strings, and list of integers.

Your question might not be super helpful to others, but I hope this answer will help you at least :) I broke my answer from the comment into shorter steps. Each step has an example of what type of data you are dealing with at the end.

```
# Read a string like "8 5 12 12 15"
encoded = input("Enter some numbers, separated by spaces: ")

# Turn the string into a list of shorter strings.
# For example: ["8", "5", "12", "12", "15"]
# you should handle input errors here, too
encoded_list = encoded.split(' ')

# Conver the list of strings to a list of integers
# For example: [8, 5, 12, 12, 15]
encoded_numbers = [int(character) for character in encoded_list]

# Decode the numbers and turn them back into strings using chr()
# For example: ["h", "e", "l", "l", "o"]
character_list = [chr(number + 96) for number in encoded_numbers]

# Finally, turn the list of characters into a single string using
# join, then print it
print("Decoded message:")
print("".join(character_list))
```

I highly recommend playing with the interactive shell (just run `python` - or even better `ipython` if you have it installed). It's easier to check what type of data a function returns and experiment with it that way.

Answer (score 3):

Now you're trying to get string and convert it to integer in first string, then you trying to put this integer into for loop.

I do not quite understand what you want from this code, but if you want to type a number of char in ascii ang get this char, use this:

```
a = input('Enter a number: ')

char = chr(int(a) + 96)

print('Decoded char: ' + char)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate over a `range` of numbers, maybe 26?.
Then you must add `97` which is the ASCII value of `a`

```
for number in range(26):
    char = f'{chr(number + 97)}'

    print (char, end=' ')
```

#### output:

```
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
```

From then on, you can easily navigate between the ASCII code and the letter representation; adding an offset modulo 26 will give you a Caesar cypher.

The reverse operation (from letter to ASCII code, to the original (0-26) number is as follows:

```
ord(char) - 97
```